# Index probably not used correctly on simple SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

Size:

- Campaigns: 3k rows (200 with campaigns.is_active = 1)
- Links: 20k rows (4k with links.status = 1 **//** 500 with links.status = 1 AND campaigns.is_active = 1)
- Clicks: 10mln rows (50k with created > '2020-10-25 00:00:00')

---

This query runs **2 seconds**

```
SELECT links.id, COUNT(clicks.id)
FROM links 
INNER JOIN campaigns ON campaigns.id = links.campaign_id 
AND campaigns.is_active = 1 
LEFT JOIN clicks ON clicks.link_id = links.id
WHERE links.status = 1 
AND clicks.created > '2020-10-25 00:00:00'
GROUP BY links.id
```

When I remove the following line, it runs just **0.13 seconds** (15 times faster)

`AND campaigns.is_active = 1`

There is an INDEX on campaigns.is_active.
Also tried to set an index on 2 columns (campaigns.id + campaigns.is_active) but didn't help.

"campaigns.is_active" contains simply 0 or 1. The campaigns table is small, the campaigns.is_active condition actually reduces the amount of rows. So it should speed up the query instead.

Why does it take so much longer because of this condition and how to fix it?

If I would remove the JOIN to campaigns and instead add links.campaign_id to the SELECT fields and then query every single of the returned campaign_id's in an additional query like "*SELECT is_active FROM campaigns WHERE id = ?*" it would still be faster, because such a query is 0.000x. From my experience when something is faster in 2 queries, it usually means the first query isn't optimized to its full extent.

Explain-Select
[image: explain-select]

Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `campaigns` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `clicks` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `link_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `links` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `campaign_id` int(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `campaigns`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id_isactive` (`id`,`is_active`),
  ADD KEY `is_active` (`is_active`)

ALTER TABLE `clicks`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `link_id` (`link_id`),
  ADD KEY `created` (`created`)

ALTER TABLE `links`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `campaign_id` (`campaign_id`),
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Added the missing information. Also added the aggregating function which I removed to simplify the query for stackoverflow

Comment: After you read this https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-performance/info please [edit] your question to give more info. And, your filter on `clicks.created` turns your LEFT JOIN into an ordinary inner JOIN.

Comment: The EXPLAIN implies that the data set is smaller than you're suggesting , but maybe I'm missing something. Incidentally, I think innodb quietly adds the pk onto the end of all indexes, so the `id` in `(id,is_active)` is somewhat redundant

Comment: Indexing a true/false or 1/0 column is not really worth because the selectivity of the index will be low and mysql cannotbmake goid use of it!

Comment: @Shadow, Depends. If 90% of the rows are `false` and you search for the 10% of rows with `true`, then it's good. But you're right if you assume the two values are more evenly split, it isn't as effective.

Comment: @BillKarwin That's the case here, 95% of rows are false, we are looking for the 5% true.

Comment: @Strawberry I updated the dataset information regarding the relevant data according to the queries conditions. I also think that an index on (id,is_active) is redudant, I just added it to test, but it didn't change anything

Comment: If I would remove the JOIN to campaigns and instead add links.campaign_id to the SELECT fields and then query every single of the returned campaign_id's in an additional query like "SELECT is_active FROM campaigns WHERE id = ?" it would still be faster, because such a query is 0.000x. From my experience when something is faster in 2 queries, it usually means the first query isn't optimized to its full extent.

Comment: @BillKarwin the question is, will mysql come to the same conclusion based on its sampling! As far as I know, mysal looks at distrubution, not individual values, so will not be aware that 5% of the values is a certain value and if the query filters at that particular value, then it should use the index, otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

How long does this take?

```
SELECT l.id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM clicks cl
        WHERE cl.link_id = l.id AND
              cl.created > '2020-10-25'
       )
FROM links l JOIN
     campaigns ca
     ca.id = l.campaign_id 
WHERE l.status = 1 AND ca.is_active = 1;
```

EDIT:

Hmmm, with an `order by`, you can try:

```
SELECT l.id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM clicks cl
        WHERE cl.link_id = l.id AND
              cl.created > '2020-10-25'
       )
FROM links l 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM campaigns ca
              WHERE ca.id = l.campaign_id AND ca.is_active = 1
             )
WHERE l.status = 1 
ORDER BY l.id;
```

For this, you want an index on `links(status, id)` and `campaigns(campaign_id, is_active)`.

Comment: I added "FROM links l" in row 3 and "ON ca.id" in row 10 and "GROUP BY l.id" at the end. It runs 0.10 seconds, but the result is wrong, the count-column always contains the overall amount of clicks since 2020-10-25

Comment: @DeveloperJano . . . I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks! It runs 0.10 seconds, but when adding ORDER BY l.id ASC it  runs 1.8 seconds again. Which is very strange because the final (grouped) result has around 500 rows, how can it take mysql so much time to order?

Comment: The new query after "edit" is running 1.8 seconds again

Comment: @DeveloperJano . . . Do you have the suggested indexes?

Comment: Yes, I set them up as "unique index" as id itself is unique, so the index on id+another column is unique too, is that correct?

Comment: @DeveloperJano . . . The indexes need to have the keys in the specified order (additional columns can be in the index *after* the specified keys).

Comment: I changed the indexes to be on links(status,id) and campaigns(id,is_active) (is that what you meant?) but it doesn't change the execution time. HAVING is still 15 times faster than WHERE, which is super strange

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not to fight the database engine optimizer.

```
SELECT links.id, campaigns.is_active, COUNT(clicks.id)
FROM links 
INNER JOIN campaigns ON campaigns.id = links.campaign_id 
LEFT JOIN clicks ON clicks.link_id = links.id
WHERE links.status = 1 
AND clicks.created > '2020-10-25 00:00:00'
GROUP BY links.id, campaigns.is_active
HAVING campaigns.is_active = 1;
```

Second variant!

```
-- Second Variant
EXPLAIN
SELECT links.id AS LinksId
      , COUNT(clicks.id) AS ClickCount
FROM links 
LEFT JOIN clicks 
    ON links.id = clicks.link_id
WHERE links.status = 1
AND clicks.created > '2020-10-25 00:00:00'
AND links.campaign_id IN (SELECT campaign_id 
                            FROM campaigns
                            WHERE is_active = 1)
GROUP BY links.id;
```

Third time is the charm! Using CTEs due to the published cardinalities.

```
-- Third time is the charm
WITH ActiveCampaigns
AS
    (SELECT *
    FROM campaigns
    WHERE is_active = 1)
SELECT links.id, COUNT(clicks.id)
FROM links 
INNER JOIN ActiveCampaigns 
    ON ActiveCampaigns.id = links.campaign_id 
LEFT JOIN clicks 
    ON clicks.link_id = links.id
WHERE links.status = 1 
AND clicks.created > '2020-10-25 00:00:00'
GROUP BY links.id;
```

Comment: this takes 0.14 seconds, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: still very strange why the engine optimizer is doing this, is there any understandable reason or any way to predict this? I wonder how many queries we have where optimisation like this would be helpful but nobody would think about it

Comment: I don't have enough data to dig deeper but it might be worth running an ANALYZE TABLE on links, campaigns and links to update the statistics.The last updated statistics can be looked at using the catalog tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats. Outdated statistics produce inefficient plans. BTW, the schema that was published is missing columns used in the SQL query.

Comment: The tables were already updated very recently when I checked, an ANALYZE TABLE didn't help. I added the missing column to the schema.

Comment: I now have the issue, when I add another join that is related to the campaigns table, that join becomes slow using the query you provided. That makes sense because the data queried from campaigns table is actually much bigger with HAVING than with WHERE. Anything else I can do?

Comment: I don't have the volumes to perform an accurate test. Please try the second variant in my edit of the answer. I'm getting favorable query plan. I could not find the field provider_id in the links table in the published schema.

Comment: the second query is 1.6s seconds (compared to 0.14 seconds of the first query with HAVING), so strange

Comment: Could you please share what version of MySQL is being used.

Comment: Sure, 10.4.15-MariaDB

Comment: Great! Published a third version of the query using CTEs. Separating the active campaigns as the cardinality is low (200). There're definitely more ways to get to the goal  of improving performance. I don't have an environment to test this!

Answer (score 0):

Question...  If a campaign is not *currently* active, you don't want any output for it, correct?  Furthermore, there won't be any clicks for inactive campaigns, correct?  Then why bother checking `is_active`?

Even if my analysis is wrong, it may be faster to ignore is_active until after the counts have been tallied.

Please don't use `LEFT` when it is not functional.  You have a simple `JOIN`.

Use `COUNT(*)`; `COUNT(x)` tests `x` for being not null.

```
SELECT  links.id, COUNT(*)
    FROM  links
    JOIN  clicks  ON clicks.link_id = links.id
    WHERE  links.status = 1
      AND  clicks.created > '2020-10-25 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY  links.id
```

This is redundant:

```
ADD UNIQUE KEY `id_isactive` (`id`,`is_active`),
```

since `PRIMARY KEY(id)` declares `id` to be an index and unique.